# How to hide a .ui file and show another .ui file in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a button on my window on GTK+ 3. When the button is clicked, a window from another ui file should be opened and the current window's ui should be deleted (Hide). But I don't know how to do so.I am really new to Gtk+ programming on linux.
this is my .c file:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void 
buttonClicked(GtkWidget *widget,
              gpointer    data)
{
//here I need to open another window and close the current one
}

int main (int   argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GObject *window;
  GObject *button;
  GError *error = NULL;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  if(gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "main-window.ui", &error) == 0)
    {
      g_printerr ("Error loading file: %s\n", error->message);
      g_clear_error (&error);
      return 1;
    }
   window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
   g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "buttonOpen");
   g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (buttonClicked), NULL);

   gtk_main ();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [gtk_widget_show_all ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-show-all) and [gtk_widget_hide ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void 
buttonClicked(GtkWidget *widget, GObject* window)
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GObject *window2;
    GError *error = NULL;
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if(gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "second-window.ui", &error) == 0)
    {
        g_printerr ("Error loading file: %s\n", error->message);
        g_clear_error (&error);
        return;
    }
    window2 = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window2));
    gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}

int main (int   argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GObject *window;  
  GObject *button;
  GError *error = NULL;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  if(gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "main-window.ui", &error) == 0)
    {
      g_printerr ("Error loading file: %s\n", error->message);
      g_clear_error (&error);
      return 1;
    }
   window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
   g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "buttonOpen");
   g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (buttonClicked), window);

   //some widgets don't draw if their parent window was not "show alled"
   gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

   gtk_main ();

   return 0;
}
```

Note that [gpointer](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.52/glib-Basic-Types.html#gpointer) is actually a `void*` so you can pass to your function whatever you like.